# Sorting an hash given another hash including information about the order method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to sort an `hash` considering a preset order by returning a sorted `array` or even a new sorted `hash`. That is, given the following `hash`, say HASH1 (for which I consider its values to indicate the order method from 1 to 4)

```
{
  :dog  => 3,
  :cat  => 2,
  :pig  => 4,
  :frog => 1
}
```

I would like to sort this other `hash` by key, say HASH2, by considering the order given in HASH1 values

```
{
  :cat  => 'cat_value',
  :dog  => 'dog_value',
  :frog => 'frog_value',
  :pig  => 'pig_value'
}
```

So, in the above case, I should have the outputted\ordered `hash` like the following:

```
{
  :frog => 'frog_value', # Order indicated by ':frog => 1' in the HASH1
  :cat  => 'cat_value',  # Order indicated by ':cat => 2'  in the HASH1
  :dog  => 'dog_value',  # Order indicated by ':dog => 3'  in the HASH1
  :pig  => 'pig_value'   # Order indicated by ':pig => 4'  in the HASH1
}
```

or

```
[
  ["frog", 'frog_value'], # Order indicated by ':frog => 1' in the HASH1
  ["cat", 'cat_value'],   # Order indicated by ':cat => 2'  in the HASH1
  ["dog", 'dog_value'],   # Order indicated by ':dog => 3'  in the HASH1
  ["pig", 'pig_value']    # Order indicated by ':pig => 4'  in the HASH1
]
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Hash#sort_by`:

```
hash = {
  :cat  => [2],
  :frog => [1],
  :pig  => [4],
  :dog  => [3]
}

order = {
  :dog  => 3,
  :cat  => 2,
  :pig  => 4,
  :frog => 1
}

# array of k, v pairs
p sorted_array = hash.sort_by {|k, v| order[k]}
p sorted_hash = Hash[sorted_array]
```

Output

```
[[:frog, [1]], [:cat, [2]], [:dog, [3]], [:pig, [4]]]
{:frog=>[1], :cat=>[2], :dog=>[3], :pig=>[4]}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. BTW: Do you know some "very" good Web resource where I can "really" learn (but mostly understand) sorting with Ruby other than the official documentation http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001481?

Comment: I think the official docs explain the key points fairly well - although the examples could've been a little better. I'm not aware of any other resource for a generic sorting in Ruby thing.