# How do I sort an Array via a custom sort order?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
[{number: 1},{number: 2}, {number: 3}, {number: 4}]
```

I need to sort them based on a custom order:

```
[3,4,1,2]
```

Thus, the result should be:

```
[{number: 3},{number: 4}, {number: 1}, {number: 2}]
```

I know `sort_by` exists but I've only used it for ascending and descending orders.

I could go crazy and not worry about performance, but is there an efficient way to order this array of hashes based on a custom order via an array?

Comment: How would the order be defined?

Comment: If I get your question right, it would be based on a custom order, in my example above it would be working off of `[2,4,1,3]`. I just need the first hash with the number value of 2 to be first, next is the hash with a number value of 4, etc.

Comment: Comparing my answer against Priti's answer, it seems like we are solving different problems. Given `order = [i,...]`, his says "put the first hash at the ith position". Mine says "the first hash should have number i". Which one are you solving?

Comment: Yours. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK I updated the input in my answer for clarity.

Comment: This has been already asked (at least a couple of times) though it's indeed difficult to track down by title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an hash given another hash including information about the order method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513855/sorting-an-hash-given-another-hash-including-information-about-the-order-method)

Comment: @theTinMan: yup, that's one of the duplicates (there must be a lot of them), though Jim Lim's answer is probably better. Sorting is not really needed.

Comment: Yes, the question gets asked often, but finding the original or best answered version is difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how one interprets the problem, a potential solution might be:

```
input  = [{number: 6},{number: 10}, {number: 2}, {number: 8}]
hash   = Hash[input.map { |h| [h[:number], h] }]
order  = [8,10,6,2]
output = hash.values_at(*order)
# => [{:number=>8}, {:number=>10}, {:number=>6}, {:number=>2}]
```

Comment: `output = hash.values_at(*order)`

Comment: OMG! you changed the question context too :)

Comment: +1 for using `values_at`. It's an extremely useful method for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
input  = [{number: 6},{number: 10}, {number: 2}, {number: 8}] 
order  = [8,10,6,2]
order.map{|i| input.find{|h| h[:number] == i }}
# => [{:number=>8}, {:number=>10}, {:number=>6}, {:number=>2}]
```

**Updated shorter code:**

```
input  = [{number: 6},{number: 10}, {number: 2}, {number: 8}] 
order  = [8,10,6,2]
input.group_by{|h| h[:number]}
# => {6=>[{:number=>6}],
#     10=>[{:number=>10}],
#     2=>[{:number=>2}],
#     8=>[{:number=>8}]}
input.group_by{|h| h[:number]}.values_at(*order)
# => [[{:number=>8}], [{:number=>10}], [{:number=>6}], [{:number=>2}]]
```

Comment: Using `shift` is destructive to `a` which might not be acceptable. Using `find` forces a repeated linear search through the array, causing an increasingly slower search as `order` or the `input` arrays grow.

Comment: @theTinMan I removed the `#shift` version.

Comment: I see that. Take a close look at @JimLim's answer, especially the code that massages `input` and creates an intermediate hash. That transform allows his code to reference the needed values using `values_at` in a very efficient/fast manner. It's a commonly used technique, transforming to an intermediate hash, then grabbing the needed results in another, arbitrary, order.

Comment: @theTinMan Please see my update. I have done using `#group_by`.

Answer (score 1):

Just sort on the index of the value in `a`

```
h = [{number: 1},{number: 2}, {number: 3}, {number: 4}]
a = [3,4,1,2]

p h.sort_by{|el| a.index(el[:number])}
# => [{:number=>3}, {:number=>4}, {:number=>1}, {:number=>2}]
```

Comment: Yes, that's a typical way to do it, only problem it's O(n^2). You can build an intermediate hash to make it O(n log n).

Comment: @tokland You are doubtlessly  right, but with these data it's two times as fast [without](http://ideone.com/rDyOG5) an intermediate hash. I don't know what is the best choice in such a case.

Comment: Indeed, with small inputs the big-O of an algorithm is usually irrelevant, it was just a note for the readers, it's often forgotten that Array#index is O(n), so using it within a loop should be a red flag.

Comment: @tokland Please see my update. I have done using `#group_by`.